# Library to plot graph without using storyboards

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I need a library for creating graphs which does not use storyboards and has various functionalities like zoom in and out. I want a library which has features similar to the library at https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph. I checked many libraries but most are using storyboards. Please reply.

Comment: have you ever had a look at CorePlot? https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot

Comment: It doesn't have zoom feature and I also want to check values on clicking at any point in the graph

Comment: I does have these features, yet it maybe complex to get them customized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through my own search and I couldn't find anything that worked exactly the way I needed it to. Finally I found a library which is used in android applications but a  new version for iOS users has been launched which is awesome. You can find the library [here](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts).

Answer (score 0):

The most popular choice of graphing system out there for iOS and OS X is [CorePlot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot) which can be difficult to use but there are lots of great [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1).

If you are looking for something simpler may I humbly suggest [RHGraphKit](https://github.com/RedHandTech/RHGraphKit) which is a simple graphing system I put together for Mac OS X 10.10+